# Notification not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSCalendar *lbCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]init];
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [lbCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComponent setYear:2014];
[dateComponent setMonth:6];
[dateComponent setDay:15];
[dateComponent setHour:22];
[dateComponent setMinute:29];

UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dp setDate:[lbCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"Hello Notification"];
[notification setFireDate:dp.date];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
```

This is my code in appdelegate.m to show a local notification but it's not working and the code is correct with no errors and the app is lunching correctly but no notifications are shown.

I'm using Xcode 5.1 with SDK 7.0

Comment: Are you sure it's not called? Did you implement `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`?

Comment: no I didn't implement that

Comment: I implemented it now but still didn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's not yet the solution to the problem, but if you place an NSLog there or set a breakpoint, it will help you debug the issue.

Comment: try just testing it with NSDate to get 5 seconds from now and seeing if that runs. If it does, then your problem is with the date's time code. Try printing your date to see when/where it is, and NSLog (or smarter, debug Log if you know how to make one) all your variables. 
Divide and conquer, ensure every piece is working. Defensive style is good for this type of thing

Comment: Also, if you're not sure about setting the fire date, you can use `    notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
` to fire the notification in exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: I tried both of them (NSDate withTimeIntervalSinceNow and dateByAddingTimeInterval) but both didn't work.

Comment: I cleaned my application and tried again the NSDate withTimeIntervalSinceNow it worked so I think the problem is from my date's time code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
NSCalendar *lbCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

instead of

```
NSCalendar *lbCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]init];
```